# Plotting shapefiles "cumulatively" in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I have a shapefile, where one column is the year ("Jahr"). I want to plot them on a shapefile ("africa") but in my solution for every year a new plot is created. I would like to have a cumulative plots of my shapefile (so in the year 1980 I can see all of the shapes since 1950.

```
library(sf)
library(giscoR)

africa <- gisco_get_countries(region = "Africa", resolution = 60, level = 1) %>%
  st_union() %>%
  st_transform(3857)

sample <- st_sample(africa, 40)
sample <- st_as_sf(sample)
sample$Jahr <- floor(runif(41, min=1950, max=1980))


ggplot(africa)+
  geom_sf()+
  geom_sf(data = sample, aes(col = "Jahr"))+
  facet_wrap( "Jahr")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would need to do this yourself in the data before plotting:

```r
library(tidyverse)

sample <- lapply(unique(sample$Jahr), 
       function(i) within(sample[which(sample$Jahr <= i),], Jahr2 <- i)
       ) %>% bind_rows()

ggplot(africa)+
  geom_sf()+
  geom_sf(data = sample, aes(col = Jahr))+
  facet_wrap(~Jahr2) +
  scale_color_gradientn(colors = c('red3', 'yellow', 'green4')) +
  theme_void(base_size = 8)
```

[image]